# JavaScript - ¿Existe una forma de iterar un array desde una posición específica?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me preguntaba si en JavaScript hay una forma de hacer esto:

```py
# Lenguaje Python
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for i in arr[::-1]: # ej: imprimir lista de forma invertida/al revés
    print(i)
```

¿La sintaxis `array[::]` existe en JavaScript, podría ser lograda de una forma similar o únicamente bajo un método?

Gracias a las respuestas, pero no busco sólo una forma de invertir el orden de un array, eso fue un ejemplo de lo que puede hacerse en la sintaxis `array[::]`, hay otros como `array[:-1]` que iterará todos excepto el último, `array[:3]` que iterará sólo los primeros 3 elementos, etc.

*También acepto soluciones con jQuery*

Comment: ¿De dónde viene la sintaxis `[::]`?

Comment: La sintaxis `array[::]` viene de Python

Comment: Uhm, ok, gracias.

Comment: Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de igualar dicha sintaxis en JavaScript o adaptarla para obtener los mismos resultados

Comment: Bueno segun lo que tu buscas sería más bien como documentación de los métodos que puedes usar sobre un array: [arrays javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)

Comment: La verdad, como desconozco Python, no creo poder ayudar :( También estaba realizando unas pruebas de código como las de los otros usuarios, pero cuando vine a escribirla, me encontré con que no era lo que necesitabas, así que ahí quedé :/ Lo siento.

Comment: @quinqui No te preocupes amigo, gracias por tu preocupación a dar una respuesta a mi pregunta :)

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es el metodo slice(). Puedes fijarte en mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: @MáximaAlekz En los sitios SE no se deben incluir etiquetas en el título. Ref. [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), por ello retiré `JavaScript - ` del título de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript no tiene ese *sugar syntax* para el bucle for. Existe el método `.forEach()`, pero siempre recorrerá el array en sentido creciente. Del mismo modo tiene `for(let i of array) {...}` para recorrer iterables (que sería lo más cerca a lo que buscas, pero no se puede invertir)

```js
const array=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

for (let i=array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Si no te importa *destruir* el array, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const array=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

while (array.length) {
  console.log(array.pop()); //pop saca del array el último elemento
}
```

Una tercera opción sería añadir a Array un método nuevo que fuese el equivalente a .forEach() pero en sentido inverso:

```js
const array = ['Hola',1,2,3,4,5,6];

Array.prototype.inverseForEach = function(callback) {
  for (let i=this.length -1 ; i >= -1; i--) {
    callback.call(this,this[i]);
  }
};

array.inverseForEach(console.log);
```

En general, hay que usar un bucle for *normal* para recorrer un array o parte de él:

```
for (let index = <valor_inicial>; <condición_a_cumplir>; index = <valor para la siguiente iteración>) {
  ...
}
```

Aunque haya multitud de métodos para trabajar con ellos: [forEach, reduce, map, some, every, filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) ...

Comment: Ésta pregunta tiene un buen sentido de explicación +1

Comment: Pablo, mas alla que tu respuesta esta buena, a nadie se le ocurrio hacer una funcion que reciba, inicio, fin y haga un for comun y corriente? creo que eso se parece mas a lo que hace python...

Answer (score 4):

En javascript puedes usar `reverse()`. El mismo invierte el orden de los elementos.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
alert(arr.reverse());
```

Creo que lo qu estás buscando es el método `slice ()`. Devuelve los elementos seleccionados en una matriz, como un nuevo objeto de matriz.

El método `slice ()` selecciona los elementos comenzando en el argumento de inicio dado, y termina en, pero no incluye, el argumento final dado.

Ej:

```
var frutas = ["Banana", "Naranja", "Limon", "Manzana", "Mango"];
var citricas = frutas.slice(1, 3);
alert (citricas);
```

Comment: Pero eso modifica el array original, no devuelve uno nuevo, hay que tener cuidado con ese detalle

Comment: Exacto, como mencioné invierte el orden del array en cuestión

Comment: Para no modificarlo puedes hacer una copia del array con slice. `arr.slice().reverse()`

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que deseas es imprimir de forma inversa los datos, te dejo el código a modo de explicación para que se comprenda la sintaxis:

Para lograr esto, solo debes obtener la longitud del arreglo con el comando **length** y solo basta con restarle 1 (los arreglos comienzan desde la posición 0, por eso restamos 1 para obtener la posición del ultimo elemento)

```js
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
    var ultimo=arr.length-1;
    for(var i=ultimo;i>=0;i--){
     console.log(arr[i])
    }
```

Comment: Imprimir de forma inversa el array fue sólo un ejemplo, yo me refería a la funcionalidad de `[::]`

Answer (score 2):

Explicación: Iteras un array desde una posicion `s` hasta una posición `f`(inclusiva) y excluyes un array de elementos, el cual es `exclude` y una función que se ejecutará la cual es `func`.

```
Array.prototype.iterate = function(s, f, exclude, func) {
 for(; s < f; ++s) {
  var cur = this[s];
  if(check_exclude(exclude, cur)) continue;
  func(cur, s, this);
 }

 function check_exclude(exclude_arr, cur) {
  return exclude_arr.some(exclude_elem => exclude_elem === cur);
 }
};
```

Y la usas así, quiero imprimir un array `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`, desde el índice `0` hasta el índice `3` y además omitir la `B`, que está en el índice `2`.

Esto me debería mostrar: `A C D`, y se comprueba que funciona:

```js
Array.prototype.iterate = function(s, f, exclude, func) {
     for(; s <= f; ++s) {
      var cur = this[s];
      if(check_exclude(exclude, cur)) continue;
      func(cur, s, this);
     }
     
     function check_exclude(exclude_arr, cur) {
      return exclude_arr.some(exclude_elem => exclude_elem === cur);
     }
    };
    
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"].iterate(0, 3, ["B"], (cur, i, arr) => {
 console.log(cur);
});
```

Comment: Muy buena implementación :) +1

Comment: Considera, marcar la respuesta que te haya servido

Answer (score 1):

No hay una sintaxis `array[::]`, mucho menos `array[:-1]` o `array[:3]`.

La única manera en la que podrías lograr algo similar sería a través de los métodos [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) y el mismo [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach).

Ambos métodos tienen los mismos parámetros en su callback: `currentValue`, `index` y `array` (Lee la documentación para que tengas más información acerca de ellos).

Ambos se diferencian en que el método filter, creará un nuevo array siempre y cuando se cumpla su condición a true. Mientras que el forEach hará lo que le pidas sin importar si es true o false, además de que sobreescribirá el array.

Te dejo unos ejemplos sobre lo que te comento. Observa que hay un filter que lo hace por el elemento actual mientras que otro lo hace por index (posición especifica del array).

```js
$(function(){
  arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
  
  $('#filtere').click(function(){
    $('#resultado').empty();
    let filtrados = arr.filter((element) => element >= 3);
  
    $('#resultado').append(filtrados);
  });
 
  $('#filteri').click(function(){
    $('#resultado').empty();
    let indexFilter = arr.filter((element, index) => index >= 3);
  
    $('#resultado').append(indexFilter);
  });
  
  $('#foreachi').click(function(){
    $('#resultado').empty();
    let texto = '';
    arr.forEach(function (currentValue, index) {
        if (index < arr.length - 3) {
          texto += currentValue;
        }
    });  
  
    $('#resultado').append(texto);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="filtere">Clic con filter por elemento</button>
<button type="button" id="filteri">Clic con filter por index</button>
<button type="button" id="foreachi">Clic con forEach por index</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar en javascript el metodo reverse() te los ordenará al reves

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

arr.reverse();

Comment: agrega mas información  a tu respuesta para que esta sea mas completa.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = arreglo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arreglo[i]
}
```

Comment: Explica mejor tu respuesta, para que lo pueda entender mejor Maxima Alekz

Comment: @Luis intenta indicarme como imprimir un array al revés. Pero como aclaré en la pregunta, esa es una de las cosas que pueden hacerse con la sintaxis `array[::]`